# Proper Way to Disable UART RX

Tags: uart

I'm doing UART communication over a single wire using voltage and current modulation with an STM32F0. The problem I'm having is when I transmit, it feeds back into my Rx circuit an I receive a bunch of junk.

I'd like to disable the Rx UART completely while I'm transmitting, then reset my Tx analog circuit (flip flop state) and then renable the Rx.

Currently when I try to do this, any delays I insert seem to break my firmware flow and I get stuck in a UART interrupt loop.

```
/* Disable Rx UART during message transmission */
USART_ITConfig(PMIC_COM1, USART_IT_RXNE, DISABLE);

/* Reply over CCIF if message 0x28 is received, reply is enabled and 
current state is LiIon */
//TODO: Reply Enable might not be necessary if checking for this in LiIon STate
if (replyEnable == 1 && currentState == STATE_LIION)
{
    CCIF_Send_Reply();
}

/* Reset Flip Flops */
PMIC_Output_On(FF_RESET);

Delay(5); 

PMIC_Output_Off(FF_RESET);

/* Enable Rx UART */
USART_ITConfig(PMIC_COM1, USART_IT_RXNE, ENABLE);  


void CCIF_Send_Reply(void)
{
  TxBuffer[0] = 0x55;
  TxBuffer[1] = 0x66;
  TxBuffer[3] = 0xFF;
  TxBuffer[4] = '\0';
  USART_ITConfig(PMIC_COM1, USART_IT_TXE, ENABLE);
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the STM32F0, but just disabling the interrupt won't stop characters from coming into the UART.  You either need to to disable the receive side of the UART itself, or clear the UART's receive FIFO (if it has one) before re-enabling interrupts.

Comment: You need to disable the receiver of uart by setting RE bit to 0 in usart control register (USARTx_CR1). See the reference manual for your controller.

Comment: USART_DirectionModeCmd(COM1, USART_Mode_Rx, DISABLE); Seems to have worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable only Receive Enable: USART_DirectionModeCmd(COM1, USART_Mode_Rx, DISABLE);

Disable entire UART: USART_Cmd(PMIC_COM1, DISABLE);